# Flask-SQLAlchemy get rid of `idle in transaction`

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've a problem with `idle in transaction` connections in my flask application.
After some time postgres automatically closes all such transactions, and application isn't able to make new connection, which results in ISE:

```
[Tue Aug 27 11:24:43.354723 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 25:tid 140264740386560] [remote 172.17.0.1:60687] sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back [SQL: 'SELECT metadata.contracts.name AS metadata_contracts_name, metadata.contracts.table_path AS metadata_contracts_table_path, metadata.contracts.abort_on_error AS metadata_contracts_abort_on_error, metadata.contracts.active AS metadata_contracts_active, metadata.contracts.timestamp AS metadata_contracts_timestamp, metadata.contracts.modified_by AS metadata_contracts_modified_by, metadata.contracts.deleted AS metadata_contracts_deleted, metadata.contracts.subscribers AS metadata_contracts_subscribers, metadata.contracts.version AS metadata_contracts_version, metadata.contracts.id AS metadata_contracts_id, metadata.contracts.group_access AS metadata_contracts_group_access, metadata.contracts.restricted_access AS metadata_contracts_restricted_access, metadata.contracts.owner AS metadata_contracts_owner, metadata.contracts.user_access AS metadata_contracts_user_access \\nFROM metadata.contracts \\nWHERE metadata.contracts.id = %(id_1)s ORDER BY metadata.contracts.version DESC \\n LIMIT %(param_1)s'] [parameters: [{}]]
```

Here're simplified views for my application:

```py
from dagama import db
from dagama.contracts import bp
from dagama.contracts.models import Contract


@bp.route('/')
def contracts():
    contracts_qs = db.session.query(Contract)
    n = contracts_qs.count()
    return Response()

@bp.route('/<int:id>/')
def contract_details(id):
    contract = Contract.query.filter(Contract.id == id).order_by(Contract.version.desc()).first_or_404()
    return Response()
```

And here are stats from production db:

```sql
datalake=# SELECT pid, application_name, client_addr, client_port, backend_start, xact_start, query_start,  wait_event, state, left(query, 64) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE APPLICATION_NAME = 'dagama' OR client_addr = '172.17.0.2' ORDER BY query_start DESC;
  pid  | application_name | client_addr | client_port |         backend_start         |          xact_start           |          query_start          | wait_event |        state        |                               left
-------+------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+---------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------
 41599 | dagama           | 172.17.0.2  |       60396 | 2019-08-27 14:34:43.75638+02  |                               | 2019-08-27 14:34:43.793666+02 | ClientRead | idle                | ROLLBACK
 18338 |                  | 172.17.0.2  |       58062 | 2019-08-27 14:09:13.919567+02 |                               | 2019-08-27 14:10:55.758383+02 | ClientRead | idle                | ROLLBACK
 30387 | dagama           | 172.17.0.2  |       43526 | 2019-08-27 14:10:55.324834+02 | 2019-08-27 14:10:55.329896+02 | 2019-08-27 14:10:55.371686+02 | ClientRead | idle in transaction | SELECT metadata.rules.id AS metadata_rules_id, metadata.rules.co
 18154 | dagama           | 172.17.0.2  |       57712 | 2019-08-27 14:09:11.633017+02 | 2019-08-27 14:09:13.906523+02 | 2019-08-27 14:09:13.982879+02 | ClientRead | idle in transaction | SELECT metadata.rules.id AS metadata_rules_id, metadata.rules.co
(4 rows)
```

Calling `contract_details()` results with connection with `state = idle in transaction`, but using `db.session` like in `contracts()` directly nicely rolls back and closes the transaction (`xact_start` is null).
Flask-SQLAlchemy should manually close thread-local session [here](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/master/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L847), but it does only for usage like in in `contracts()`.

I've found SA post with similar problem: [Flask and SQLAlchemy causes a lot of IDLE in transaction connections in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27271516/flask-and-sqlalchemy-causes-a-lot-of-idle-in-transaction-connections-in-postgres), but without any clean solution which closes sessions automatically.

**edit**
One of the solutions may be manually rolling back session to which requested object is attached:

```py
@bp.route('/<int:id>/')
def contract_details(id):
    contract = Contract.query.filter(Contract.id == id).order_by(Contract.version.desc()).first_or_404()
    db.session.object_session(contract).rollback()
    return Response()
```

Comment: in the mentioned thread people are mentioning that for some of them it occurs when running in flask debug mode, isn't that the case here too?

Comment: No, the problem occurs on production as well (ofc debug=False is set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, root of the problem was found and was connected to my model definition.

I've created new `SQLAlchemy()` object instead of the one initialized with the app.

So instead of

```py
db = SQLAlchemy()


class Contract(db.Model):
...
```

I should have:

```py
from dagama import db


class Contract(db.Model):
...
```

That's why calling `Contract.query...` generated connection which wasn't handled properly after app context was destroyed.