# Idle in transaction connections while using Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy in conjunction with a postgres db and have used db.session.commit() after all update and insert calls, but my service runs a lot of SELECT queries and those connections don't get dropped and go into 'idle in transaction'.

The flask-sqlalchemy documentation doesn't mention anything about commiting  or closing after select statements either.

What is the best practice for handling these connections?

Comment: Both https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47865981/sqlalchemy-idle-in-transaction and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27271516/flask-and-sqlalchemy-causes-a-lot-of-idle-in-transaction-connections-in-postgres have close relation to your issue. How do you know you got an answer which is okay for you?

Comment: Both the questions you have mentioned make use of SQLAlchemy , I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy . In fact, one of the proposed solutions to the questions is to use flask-sqlalchemy as it is supposed to handle connections created and dropping

Comment: [It indeed is supposed to do that](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/master/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L851), though not through dropping connections, but [removing the thread-local session](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/contextual.html#sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session.remove) at teardown of an [application context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/appcontext/).